# Geometric Proofs That Avoid Law of Cosines

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm looking for a simple way to solve triangles without using the Law of Cosines. For example, given a triangle $\Delta ABC$ with $AB = 5, BC = 8, m\angle ABC = 120^\circ$, it's easy to find $AC$ with the Law of Cosines. I'm interested in solving this purely geometrically (i.e., no trig).

Comment: Law of cosines here?

Comment: Good catch Bob Dobbs. Edited.

Comment: Purely geometrically, given an angle already constructed and two lengths $AB$ and $BC$, you transfer the lengths to the angle with compass and straightedge and now you have constructed the length $AC.$ But I guess you want something more like a generalized Pythagorean Theorem where you can algebraically find the numerical length using relatively simple operations such as multiplication, addition, and the square root. But we can compute $\cos(\angle ABC)$ from the answer to your question, so if there were an algebraic solution then the trig functions wouldn't be transcendental.

Comment: In your particular case, we do have a geometric way to show that the cosine of $120^\circ$ is $\frac12,$ so we can use that same construction to find $AC.$ But you phrased the question as if you want it to work for arbitrary angles. Do you really want arbitrary angles or are you interested in special angles?

Comment: The true problem is with sides $a$ and $b$ making an angle of $\alpha$. In this general case you simply can follow the proof of Law of Cosinus which is easy (it would be a trickery but have you another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well-known question. Trick is extending one side. Extend the side $BC$, drop a perpendicular $AD$ from $A$ to this extended side to form a triangle $\triangle ADB$. Then, $\triangle ADB$ is a right-triangle with $\angle DAB=30$ and $\angle DBA=60$.

Now, $\sin30=\frac{1}{2}\implies DB=\frac{5}{2}$ and $\sin60=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\implies DA=\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2}$. And thus, we also have $DC=DB+BC=\frac{5}{2}+8=\frac{21}{2}$.

Then, Pythagorean theorem for the triangle $\triangle ADC$ gives $AD^2+DC^2=AC^2\implies AC^2=(\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2})^2+(\frac{21}{2})^2=\frac{75}{4}+\frac{441}{4}=\frac{516}{4}=129\implies AC=\sqrt{129}.$

Comment: Anthology! Someone puts a downvote and another rates this answer as the best. Any stupid concerned?

Comment: @If you can't draw pictures, please avoid geometry...

Comment: :- Nothing against you Bob I don't know why i received your message by mail. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to do. I'll show my solution and add an explanation as well:

[image]

1.) Extend $AB$ until it meets $D$ outside $\triangle ABC$. Also connect $C$ with $D$ via $CD$ such that $AD\perp CD$. Notice that since $\angle ABC=120$, it implies that $\angle DBC=60$.

2.) Above implies that $\triangle DBC$ is a "$30-60-90$" triangle and $\triangle ADC$ is a right triangle. This proves that length $BD$ is half of length $BC$, therefore $BD=4$. Moreover, this also means that length $CD=4\sqrt{3}$.

3.) Lastly, we can see that $AD=9$ and $CD=4\sqrt{3}$, therefore:

$$AC^2=AD^2+CD^2$$

$$AC^2=81+48$$

$$AC=\sqrt{129}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
A C &=\sqrt{\left(\frac{21}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{5 \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt{129}
\end{aligned}
$$
[image]